# FindMaximum with Integer value

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Define the following vectors and matrices:

```
v1={2,0}
v2={0,1}
v3={2,1}
S={{2,0},{0,1}}
A={{2,0},{0.311,1}}
```

I need to find the maximum of $\displaystyle{\frac{|S(n_1v_1+n_2v_2)+A(n_3v_3)|}{|n_1v_1+n_2v_2+n_3v_3|}}$ for $n_1,n_2,n_3\in \mathbb{Z}$ with the condition $|n_1v_1+n_2v_2+n_3v_3|\neq 0$.

I thought the following code would do the job:

```
FindMaximum[{Norm[S.(n1*v1) + S.(n2*v2) + A.(n3*v3)]/
Norm[n1*v1 + n2*v2 + n3*v3], Norm[n1*v1 + n2*v2 + n3*v3] > 0, 
n1 \[Element] Integers,n2 \[Element] Integers,n3 \[Element] Integers}, {n1, n2, n3}]
```

But, instead of the solution, I get in output the following error:

> Constraints in \
>   {n1[Element]Integers,Sqrt[Abs[n2+n3]^2+Abs[Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]]\
>   ^2]>0} are not all equality or inequality constraints. With the \
>   exception of integer domain constraints for linear programming, \
>   domain constraints or constraints with Unequal (!=) are not \
>   supported. >>

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: You entered a nonlinear integer optimization problem. Such problems can be quite hard and there are few numerical methods that can solve such problems. The error message tells you that `FindMaximum` can only handle _linear_ optimization problems over _integer_ numbers  and _nonlinear_ optimization problems over _real_ numbers.

Comment: @Bill I fixed it, but the error message is the same

Comment: Based on a little experimentation it looks like you might find your maximum by choosing a large positive integer value b and then `n1= -b; n2=n1+1; n3=b;` and you get your maximum. The bigger the b the bigger the maximum, to infinity and beyond. Please test that claim carefully before you depend on it.

Comment: @Bill Thank you very much for your observation. Without the conditions of $n_i$ being integers Mathematica returned the result 2.00337 with a warning message ("The algorithm does not converge to the tolerance of \
4.806217383937354`*^-6 in 500 iterations..."). How is that it didn't state that the function is unbounded? Also, would you please explain how did you test the claim to note that the function is unbounded?

Comment: The help pages show `FindMaximum` uses methods that can find a local maximum. The help pages show `Maximize` uses very different methods that can find a global maximum given certain conditions. With my conditions on `n1,n2,n3` it instantly reports there is no maximum. I found my claim with a little Monte Carlo searching followed by brute force larger and larger nested For loops to confirm my conjecture. Then @Carl Woll showed what I had hoped you might discover for yourself. If you remove the integer condition then you might `Plot` your expression to see what it does.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind sharing your code including Monte Carlo searching  followed by brute force larger and larger nested For loops?

Comment: `best= -Infinity;
Do[{n1,n2,n3}=RandomInteger[{-100,100},3];
If[Norm[n1*v1+n2*v2+ n3*v3]>0,zed = Norm[S.(n1*v1)+S.(n2*v2)+A.(n3*v3)]/Norm[n1*v1+n2*v2+n3*v3]; 
  If[best<zed, best=zed; Print[{N[best],n1,n2,n3}]]]
 , {10^6}]` and `best= -Infinity;
For[n1= -100,n1<=100,n1++,For[n2= -100,n2<=100,n2++,
For[n3= -100,n3<=100,n3++,
If[Norm[n1*v1+n2*v2+n3*v3]>0, zed = Norm[S.(n1*v1)+S.(n2*v2)+A.(n3*v3)]/Norm[n1*v1+ n2*v2+n3*v3]; If[best<zed,best=zed; Print[{N[best],n1,n2,n3}]]]]]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @Bill's comment. The maximum is $\infty$. Consider:

```
Norm[S.(n1*v1)+S.(n2*v2)+A.(n3*v3)]/Norm[n1*v1+n2*v2+n3*v3] /. {n1->-n3,n2->-n3-1}
```

> Abs[-1 + 0.622 n3]

The expression grows without bound as $n3 \to \infty$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Without the conditions of $n_i$ being integers Mathematica returned the result 2.00337 with a warning message ("The algorithm does not converge to the tolerance of \ 4.806217383937354`*^-6 in 500 iterations..."). How is that it didn't state that the function is unbounded?